# ffmpeg/opencv How to perform Edge Detection after classify Type of frames

Tags: c++, opencv, ffmpeg

I want to generate edge map of I-frame only in a video streaming applications (server). Below is code to generate type of frame in ffmpeg.

```
AVFrame *frame; 
pictType = av_get_picture_type_char(frame->pict_type);
```

After this step, I don't know how to process frame (using opencv c++) to have its edge map.

As I am a beginner in ffmpeg, I hope you can give me a simple example to understand this issue.

Answer (score 2):

First thing you need to do is convert the AVFrame to cv::Mat. For this, I suggest you take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29263090/ffmpeg-avframe-to-opencv-mat-conversion).

After that, you choose an edge detection algorithm implemented in OpenCV and apply it to the image. For starters, I recommend Canny edge detection, so

```
cv::Mat img; //your image, converted from AVFrame
cv::Mat edges; //output image
cv::Canny(img,edges,th1,th2);
```

Which will give you a binary map representing edges.

You need two thresholds, which depend on your images. For the first try, just try some values to get a feel for it. Later, you can look into techniques of estimating good values for these thresholds.